# RegEx for matching words preceding commas (Lua)

Tags: regex, string, split, lua

The section of text I'm targeting always begins with “Also there is” and ends with a period. The single names in between the commas is what I'm trying to target (i.e. "randomperson" in the example below. These names will always be different. It gets tricky because there’s other things present that are not single word “names”. Maybe I can match everything in between the commas ONLY IF it’s a single word/name, but I cant seem to figure that one out. The list of names could be much longer or even shorter, so the expression must be dynamic and not just match a set amount of names.

#### Targeted Text:

> Also there is a reinforced stone wall, a wooden wall, a stone wall,
> randomperson, a lumbering earth elemental, randomperson, randomperson,
> randomperson.

Group  1 of: `Also there is (.*).`

Targets everything after the "is", but then I need to somehow isolate the single words.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could use a capturing group `, (\w+)(?=,|.$)` https://regex101.com/r/K2tnjP/1

Comment: Show your code please to see where you are stuck.

Comment: `for word in ((your_text:match"Also there is(.-)%." or "")..","):gmatch"%s*([^,]*)," do if not word:match"%S%s+%S" then print(word) end end`

Comment: @Salandor, please add the code you have to the question. We should know what regex library you are using, otherwise we may post an irrelevant answer. Note that Lua itself does not support regex, it only has Lua patterns support that do not provide the full regex potential.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
s = "Also there is a reinforced stone wall, a wooden wall, a stone wall, randomperson, a lumbering earth elemental, randomperson, randomperson, randomperson."
str = s:sub(15,-2)
things = {}
start = 1
while true do
  a, b = str:find("[^,]+", start)
  if not a then break end
  table.insert(things, str:sub(a, b))
  start = b + 3
end
for _,thing in ipairs(things) do print("-> " .. thing) end
```

which outputs

```
-> a reinforced stone wall
-> a wooden wall
-> a stone wall
-> randomperson
-> a lumbering earth elemental
-> randomperson
-> randomperson
-> randomperson
```

Or install a luarocks module [split](https://luarocks.org/modules/telemachus/split) and it's as simple as

```
split = require("split")
things = split.split(s:sub(15,-2), ", ")
```

Using `gmatch`:

```
for thing in s:sub(14, -2):gmatch("%f[%S][^,]+") do print(thing) end
```

I'm using a "frontier" pattern there to discard the space that follows the comma.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about the direction of the question, but the problem may be too complex for regular expressions, let alone Lua patterns. And since I like grammars - here is some [LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg):

```lua
local l = require "lpeg";
local V, P, R, S = l.V, l.P, l.R, l.S;
local OUT = function(T, ... ) return function(...) print(T, ...) end end

local g = P{ "S",
    S = 'Also there is ' * V'List' * '.',
    List = V'Item' * (P',' * ' ' * V'Item')^0,
    Item = V'Specific_Noun' + V'Name',
    Name = V'Word'                                                   /OUT'Name',
    Specific_Noun = (P'a' + 'an') * ' ' * (V'Word' * ' ')^0 * V'Noun',
    Noun = V'Word'                                                   /OUT'Noun',
    Word = R('az','AZ')^1,
}

g:match("Also there is a reinforced stone wall, a wooden wall, a stone wall, "..
"randomperson, a lumbering earth elemental, randomperson, randomperson, rando"..
"mperson, Karl, Greta, a mile.")
```

Example output:

```
Noun    wall
Noun    wall
Noun    wall
Name    randomperson
Noun    elemental
Name    randomperson
Name    randomperson
Name    randomperson
Name    Karl
Name    Greta
Noun    mile
```

This grammar can obviously only parse vastly simplified listings, but it will match your basic requirements and can be quite easily expanded.